# How to load the content onclick menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have vertical menu. when I click on each menu it should load the content and should display..
here I have my code

```
  <ul id="menu">
        <li class="selected"><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="menu_home" onClick="highlightTab('home')">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="menu_about" onClick="highlightTab('about')">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="menu_technologies" onClick="highlightTab('technologies')">Technologies</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="menu_services" onClick="highlightTab('services')">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="menu_contact" onClick="highlightTab('contact')">Contact Us</a></li>    
    </ul>

<div id="menu1">
<div class="display" id="menu_home" >
<h3>home page</h3>
</div>
<div class="display"  id="menu_about">
<h3>details about the page</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

so if i click on home menu in div it should show the home page..first function is to highlight the selected menu
and here my jquery

```
function highlightTab(link_id){
        $("a[id^='menu_']").parent().removeClass('selected');
        $("#menu_"+link_id).parent().addClass('selected');
            }

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#selected').on('click','a',function()
    {
        $('.display:visible').fadeOut();
           $('.display[id='+$(this).attr('id')+']').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

this is my css code

```
ul#menu li.selected{
        background-color:black;     
        color:white;
    }

.display
{
    left: 734px;
    position: relative;
}
```

How to do it?

Comment: [This](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) might interest you

Comment: And, ID's must be unique.

Comment: iam giving unique id only..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some thing wrong with your code:

- You've 2 the same ID's (the A and the DIV), updated with data-target.
- You were searching for "#selected" instead of ".selected", updated this to #menu.
- In [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f1mhu6jc/) the highlightTab function isn't being found. Why not mixing those two like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tfnvr7bL/1/)?

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="selected"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-target="menu_home" onClick="highlightTab('home')">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-target="menu_about" onClick="highlightTab('about')">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-target="menu_technologies" onClick="highlightTab('technologies')">Technologies</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-target="menu_services" onClick="highlightTab('services')">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-target="menu_contact" onClick="highlightTab('contact')">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="menu1">
    <div class="display" id="menu_home">

<h3>home page</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="display" id="menu_about">

<h3>details about the page</h3>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function highlightTab(link_id) {
    $("a[id^='menu_']").parent().removeClass('selected');
    $("#menu_" + link_id).parent().addClass('selected');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu').on('click', 'a', function () {
        $('.display:visible').fadeOut();
        $('.display[id="' + $(this).data('target') + '"]').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
ul#menu li.selected {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
.display {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Check the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfnvr7bL/1/) here as indicated in the last point of my list :-).